# Action buttons in data tables

Tags: web-app, icons, data-tables, usability-engineering

Please consider the following two options:

1. Just an edit button in the Caller ID column.
   [image]
2. Edit and remove buttons in the Caller ID column.[image]

Removing a caller ID will seldom be done. You would do it if a number was mistakenly assigned to a location for which you do not have a caller ID yet, but this would be a rare occurrence.

Using option 1 to remove a caller ID forces an extra click over option 2 (a confirmation dialog for the removal would still be necessary). However, users will come to this page 99% of the times to set up a new caller ID or change an existing one. My concern with option 2 is that -to facilitate 1% of the use cases- users may be confused, even if momentarily, by the presence of the remove buttons in the data grid.

What option would you use? Can you think of a better approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In think the first option of the two is the best. The pencil is a logical symbol for editing. And it would only be a waste of space if you would put the cross for deleting there, if it is not used often.

However, I would prefer to not have the radio buttons there on your popup window.

Instead, I would have a smaller [x] or trashcan button on the left of the cancel button, lined out to the left. And some space between the delete and cancel button. 
OR the x or trashcan directly to the left of the number field.

In my opinion, that would seem logical.

Comment: Thank you. I am inclined to agree with you and I do not like the radio buttons either.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could solve the problem by not displaying any of those buttons, but instead:

1. Facilitating the editing of an item by clicking on the relevant row, and
2. Hiding the lesser-used action of deleting within an action menu. As in my mockup below:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW2kzo.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Gino. I like that approach, but it would not be consistent with the rest of our application. We have action buttons for data tables elsewhere.